# How to record an temporary value?

Tags: sql, database-design

I have an asset tacker with three tables (Assets, Tickets, Notes) used to record maintenance request. If an asset is placed temporarily out of service I would like to record this with the date. When placed back in service this data will be removed.

Recording it in the Assets table will result in a lot of Null fields. Recording it in the Tickets table seems awkward if there is more than one open ticket for the asset. Recording it in a new table adds complexity to queries.

Is there a best way to deal with this kind of temporary information?

Comment: It may not suit your requirements now, but it would probably be better to have a seperate events table that has a record for each out of service and back into service event. Because someone eventually might want to know utilisation, availability etc. I don't know if your use case is that complex, but knowing when something last went out of service and how long it was for (as well as all of the other times it went out of service) is a pretty key requirement for asset management. There's no harm in recording the most recent from-to outage in the base table to simplify queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see null fields as a bad thing, personally.

If all you need to know is if the asset is temporarily out of service, you could just have a field along the lines of is_temporarily_out_of_service with a 'Y', 'N'.

You get get more detailed, with an asset_status with 'Active', 'Out of service', 'Lost' etc (or IDs that link to a status table).

I'm not sure of what other queries you have, adding complexity to them I don't think should be a reason not to do something beneficial. Having another table that stored the history of an asset, so, Status, status_start_date, status_end, and maybe some Notes and infer from that would be fine, depending on your requirements